# Multiplying matrices in c using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, memory-address

When I input both the matrices, the resultant matrix doesn't show the proper answer, is my algorithm wrong or I am not supposed to use pointers in that way?
 Please help!

```
main() {

    int a[3][3],b[3][3],c[3][3],*p[3],*q[3],*r[3],j1=0;

    // 1st Matrix

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // 2nd matrix

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // Assigning pointers

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) p[i]=&a[i][0];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) q[i]=&b[i][0];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) r[i]=&c[i][0];

    // Resultant Matrix

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        *(*(r+i)+j1) = 0;
        for(j1=0;j1<3;j1++){
            printf("%d\t",*(*(r+i)+j1));
             *(*(r+i)+j1) += *(*(p+i)+j1) * *(*(q+j1)+i);
        }
        j1 = 0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: "is my algo wrong?" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It would be a lot easier to understand the code if the variables had useful names...

Comment: the equation to calculate the resultant matrix wrong?

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update edit your question to include the data you input and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops iterate through two dimensions and perform an element-wise multiplication of the arrays `a` and `b` with `b` transposed. I suspect you want to perform a matrix multiplication rather than an element-wise multiplication. To do that, you need three loops:

- Two loops iterate indices `i` and `j` through the rows and columns of `c`.
- One loop iterates some variable, say `k`, through the common dimension of `a` and `b` and sums the products of `a[i][k]` with `b[k][j]`.

Comment: Shit. I just realized the mistake I am committing. That j1 variable used in the resultant pointer pointer to the c array. Thanks.