# Multiply matrices in C using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, multiplication

First of all I apologize if I write something wrong, english is not my main language, and second, I'm new at developing world so... I'm kinda noob at programming hahaha

I'm developing a code in C **using pointers** (and this is my difficulty) where the program reads two matrices, prints them and performs their sum, so far so good. The problem is that I need to multiply them, and I'm not able to understand what logic I have to use.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void lerMatriz(int *mat, int m, int n){ //"readMatrix" in english :)
    int lin, col;
    for(lin=0; lin<m; lin=lin+1){
        for(col=0; col<n; col=col+1){
            printf("[%d][%d]: ", lin, col);
            scanf("%d", &mat[lin*n+col]);
        }
    }
}

void printaMatriz(int *mat, int m, int n){ //print the two matrices
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0; i<m; i=i+1){
        k = i * n;
        for(j=0; j<n; j=j+1){
            printf("%3d", mat[k + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void somaMatriz(int *a, int *b, int *result, int m, int n){ //realize the sum of the matrices
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0; i<m; i=i+1){
        k = i*n;
        for(j=0; j<n; j=j+1){
            result[k+j] = a[k+j] + b[k+j];
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int m, n, *m1, *m2, *m3;
    
    printf("Lines: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    printf("\nInsert the data of the first matrix:\n");
    m1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * m * n);
    m2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * m * n);
    m3 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * m * n);
    lerMatriz(m1, m, n);
    
    printf("\n\nInsert the data of the second martix:\n");
    lerMatriz(m2, m, n);
    
    printf("\nInserted arrays:\n");
    printaMatriz(m1, m, n);
    printf("\n");
    printaMatriz(m2, m, n);
    
    printf("\n\nSum of the Matrices:\n");
    somaMatriz(m1, m2, m3, m, n);
    printaMatriz(m3, m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

I saw some forums and pages, after I tried something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993711/multiplying-matrices-in-c-using-pointers) too but idk how to fit it in my code so... As I said, I'm new on it :/

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a question of programming, but rather that of mathematics. Can you multiply two matrices with pencil and paper? If not, you need to read some book about linear algebra and matrices, not ask programming questions, they will not help you one bit.

Comment: Hi! no problems being a noob or having trouble with english :)  --- It is hard to answer this question without seeing what you've tried, or posting a "minimal reproducible example" of some sample code with a problem in it. Do you understand how the math of matrix multiplication works?

Comment: You seem to know how to get a specific element of one matrix. Use the same technique to get any arbitrary element from the matrixes. Perhaps use a function to get or set the values of an arbitrary position to make it easier to read and understand?

Comment: Agreed. At a glance the code is good (although it defies convention a bit by iterating i to m vertically instead of horizontally), but the matrix multiplication algorithm is wrong. When you multiply two matrices you are doing either a dot product or a cross product. But neither of those just does Cij = Aij Bij. And you cannot assume that the result will have the same dimensions as either input. If A has n columns then B must have n rows, and the output will have the same number of rows as A and the same columns as B.

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes I have studied matrices before, my problem is even in the part of programming this, in fact, programming without using a pointer I did without any problem, I just can't replicate using pointers :(

Comment: I don't get it. You know how to access an element with indices `i` and `j` using pointers. What else do you need?

Comment: @GandhiGandhi Yes, I understand it, i'll uptade the code sending what I did whithout  pointers

Comment: @Howlium Wow, it's true, thanks for remembering this little rule, I really forgot about it haha